# GtkBox: Insert widget at position

Tags: gtk

How do I insert a GtkWidget at a specific location of a GtkBox?

I have

```
GtkWidget *item = ...;
GtkBox* list = ...;
gint pos = ...;
```

Now I want to place the `item` into the `list` at postion `pos`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add the widget, then reorder it using [`gtk_box_reorder_child()`](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkBox.html#gtk-box-reorder-child).